# Мультиязык 1С и 1С-Битрикс

Tags: битрикс, 1с

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно можно реализовать такую схему: у нас на сайте (1С-Битрикс) есть три языка (Русский, Английский и Украинский). Хотим сделать, чтобы была синхронизация номенклатуры с 1С для разных языков. Какие могут быть варианты реализации?

Answer (score 1):

**Если каталоги товаров не пересекаются (три разных каталога) или есть существенные различия**

1. На сайте: сделать три инфоблока для каждого языка с различным значением "Внешний код"
2. В 1С: настроить три вида выгрузок файла импорта `import.xml`, указав в параметре `<Ид>` соответствующий каждому языку внешний код, например `<Ид>592b7b64-87f8-4f92-86db-a59687325b67</Ид>`

[Описание свойств import.xml](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/sale/xml/import.php)

**Если каталог один, различия в названиях и описании товаров, ценах**

1. На сайте: сделать один инфоблок, добавив свойства "Название (en)", "Название (ua)". Название для русской версии уже есть - "Название". Аналогично сделать для описания. С ценами немного другая ситуация, доп поля создавать не нужно.
2. В 1С: настроить один вид выгрузки файла импорта `import.xml` и цен `offers.xml`, добавив в `import.xml` дополнительные реквизиты "Название (en)", "Название (ua)", ...

**Настройка вывода соответствующего языка на сайте**

Самый удобный способ - использовать поддомены, например `ru.site.ru`.

По условию "поддомен":

- для варианта с тремя инфоблоками: в качестве параметра компонента каталог в `IBLOCK_ID` подставлять требуемый ID
- для варианта с одним инфоблоком: сделать три однотипных шаблона, где выводить `NAME`, `NAME_EN` или `NAME_UA`, либо в [result_modifier.php](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=2830) менять `NAME` на один из языковых вариантов и использовать только один шаблон.

Answer (score 1):

Изучите как храниться номенклатура в ващей целевой конфигурации 1с. У нас например, релизовно хранение наименований на разных языках в объекте 1с "регистр сведений". Языков больше десяти. В "типовых конфигурациях 1С" реализовано не так. Но у номенклатуры 1с, как и у любого другого справочника в 1с есть уникальный идентификатор "GUID". Его и можно использовать как ключ.